# Delete Rows in Excel Worksheet if a specified cell is not equal to a cell in other sheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a Excel Workbook, with two sheets, Sheet1 and Master. I am trying to take the value of Cell(1,1) in Sheet1 while looping through the rows in column A of Master. If Cell(X, 1) where X is the current row in Master(X starts from 2) is not equal to the value of Cell(1,1) in Sheet1 then delete that row, keep looping until the last row. This is a VBScript I am trying to write. The problem I am having is that some rows are being deleted but not all are. I think some of the issues is that I seem to be getting a runtime error, and a popup regarding Data Link Properties.

```
Dim fso
Dim directory`

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True`


Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set directory = fso.GetFolder("H:\folder")`

For Each f In directory.Files
    Set objwb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(f)
    Set objwsMaster = objwb.Sheets("Master")
    Set objwsSheetOne = objwb.Sheets("Sheet1")`

    TotalRowCountMaster = objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.Sheets("Master").UsedRange.Rows.count

    uniqueCodeCheck = objwsSheetOne.Cells(1, 1).Value

    For x = 2 to TotalRowCountMaster
        On Error Resume Next
        If uniqueCodeCheck = objwsMaster.Cells(x, 1).Value Then
             objwsMaster.Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
    Next

    objwb.Save
    objwb.Close
```

Comment: could it be that it just skips rows ? cause your loop keeps going even tho the rows change. What i mean is if you delete Row 3 than Row 4 becomes the new Row 3 (your list gets shortend) but the loop keeps going and jumps to the next one wich is then former Row 5. So everytime you delet a row you need to do x=x-1

Comment: Ah! I just realized that. How might I fix this issue?

Comment: `For x = TotalRowCountMaster to 2                        x = x - 1` ? Or do I need a while loop?

Comment: For x = TotalRowCountMaster to 2 Step -1

Comment: I just tried that out. It still doesn't seem to be deleting correctly, also I keep getting a Data Link Properties popup.